# Adding an observer to a ViewController that hasn't been loaded yet

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

So here's my situation. I am using `SWRevealViewController` and on the rear VC I have some UI elements that need to be updated when a notification comes through. My problem is that the view may not be visible (and thus isn't loaded) when the notification comes through, so obviously the view hasn't had a chance to register its observers. As a workaround, I tried to instantiate the view controller in my `AppDelegate` before I post the notification, and originally when I tried this, the `IBOutlets` were nil. Then I found another question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801889/applicationdidfinishlaunchingwithoptions-firing-notification-before-destinatio)) that suggested using the `initWithCoder` method since this is called when the View Controller is instantiated from the storyboard. However, even using this practice my `IBOutlets` are still nil. Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here, or not?

AppDelegate Code (in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification`):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryabord(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let menuVC = storyboard.instantiaveViewControllerWithIdentifier("menuVC")
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter.addObserver(menuVC, selector: "updateMessagesBadge:", name: "notificationName", object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter.postNotification("notificationName", object: nil)
```

MenuVC Code:

```
required init?(coder: aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    //what to do here?
}

func updateMessagesBadge(notification: NSNotification) {
    //try to change outlet properties, but outlets are nil
}
```

Comment: i have used swrevealviewcontroller in many of my application. i have also done similar like you want. In App Delegate you need to instantiate view controller as well as it should be available as part of view hierarchy then and then iboutles would not be nil. as well as you need to implement initwithcoder and awakefromnib method in your viewcontroller. In appdelegate after instantiation, also add that controller's object reference as refernece for nsnotifcaioncenter. if you can share code i can integrate what you want.

Comment: Okay I'll update my question with the code I was trying to use.

Comment: I had a similar problem, my approach was to hold the incoming data in a cache then first thing when `viewloads` was to check that cache and update the changes.  Although that is a completely different approach then what you ask for, maybe it would help...

Comment: Yea I do have it working that way. Set the value when I receive the notification in AppDelegate, then get that value for original load, and then don't remove the observer and every time after that it works fine, but I'm still interested to see if it's possible to do it the way I originally wanted to. Always like to learn!